# How do I solve the nuxt static image caching problem?

Tags: image, nuxt.js, browser-cache

I have a static image cache problem in the browser.

I am displaying an image from the static folder in my project and when I change the content of the image without the image name change, the browser cannot detect it.

I want Nuxt to cache this image based on the modified date, or somehow detect this change and display the image over. is there a solution to this?

Comment: Do you have this issue in development or production?

Comment: my problem is when i throw it to host after production. There are no problems in the development.

Comment: You can always simulate a hash generation to the image, if you **really** want it out of `assets`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually nuxt does this out of the box - at least in the production builds and when you load the images from the `assets` folder.

For assets in the `assets` folder, webpack generates a hash and appends it to the filename at build time. If the content of the image changes, the hash changes as well. This way the browser knows when to load the updated image from the server.

Check here for reference: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/assets/#webpack

The `static` folder is not processed by webpack by default and therefore the hash is not added to the filename.

So try to make use of the `assets` folder, then the caching problem should be solved.

Comment: I know this. but only because i think compiling for an image change is unnecessary. The reason why I added some files in the static folder is to interfere with the fixed contents without depending on the compilation.

Comment: @vulkan why not bundling an image?

Comment: because we keep build files in a different place after build. an image can be a content change. We don't want to recompile for just one image and submit the build files.

It solves the "assets" cache problem, but we do not prefer it because it cannot be manipulated after compilation.

Comment: Do you have access to the date of the content update somewhere in your app? Then you could request the image like `/images/test.jpg?{timestampOfUpdate}`

Comment: Yep, this is indeed a viable solution.

Comment: In a static folder, we thought of adding the changeable version information of the image as the version in a js file and displaying it with the url information it will get from this js file when the image content is changed. This was the first thing we thought. but we wanted to ask if there is a different way because we don't know.